# Showing Array result on an input text js

Tags: javascript

i am trying to show the price of each item on the price input, i am not able to make the function work. i am not sure how to write the string on  or if i am even doing the function correctly. can you please help me? thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Price Calculation</title>
</head>

<body>
<Label>Choose Item</Label>
<select onChange=".......">
  <option>Tomatoes</option>
  <option>Lettuce</option>
  <option>Potato</option>
  <option>Carrots</option>
  <option>Artichoke</option>
</select>
<br/>
<Label>Price</Label>
  <input type="text" id="price" />
<br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var veggy = new Array ()
  veggy ["Tomatoes"] = 5.99 
  veggy ["Lettuce"] = 7.66 
  veggy ["Potato"] = 4.52 
  veggy ["Carrots"] = 2.13 
  veggy ["Artichoke"] = 10.58

function ()
{
    var veggy = document.getElementById("price")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<label>` must be lowercase. HTML elements don't support capital letters at the beginning.
And close your lines in JavaScript with `;`.

Comment: Please don't apply the changes to your initial question as other users won't see what you've done wrong and what are corrections.

Comment: Rolled back to the original version of the question. Please leave your original code intact for the benefit of future users having similar issues.

Comment: got it, will not change original posts again. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to change here:

You'd want an object with each choice as a key, and each price as a value - not an array
Call your function `onchange` and pass in the `select` element via `this`

```
//Make veggy an object
var veggy = {};
veggy["Tomatoes"] = 5.99;
veggy["Lettuce"] = 7.66;
veggy["Potato"] = 4.52;
veggy["Carrots"] = 2.13; 
veggy["Artichoke"] = 10.58;
```

Change your `select` `onChange`:

```
<select onChange="getPrice(this);">
```

And your function:

```
function getPrice(select) {
    document.getElementById("price").value = veggy[select.value];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now its showing me the name of the veggy instead of the price....edited original post to show you. thank you!

Comment: @user3807992 -- You missed the last line - `document.getElementById("price").value = veggy[select.value];`

Comment: @user3807992 -- There should be an outline of a check mark next to my answer - clicking it will "Accept" the answer.